# Any Linux app for recuperating data from Android devices (discarded email from Gmail draft)?

Tags: android, data-recovery, email, gmail, data-loss

One reason why I appreciate Linux is that it has the amazing ability to give solutions for any kind of IT-related problem.

I have an Samsung phone running Android GingerBread. I've spend my entire last week editing - while being in offline mode - one very long and important email. But today, I have accidentally discarded the message. As a result, the draft just disappeared! It's not even in trash.

Naturally, I've searched on web for a solution, looked on the Android-centred forums and sites. Apparently, there is no solution. At least, not on the Android side.

But I know from my own personal experience, that, when my Android devices had technical problems, not, Android, not Windows, but Linux was the one that helped me to see, to repair and recover the information from those devices.

So, now, I want to know if anyone of you knows any tool that could help me access informations stored deep inside Android. Frankly, I find hard to believe that once you hit the "discard" button you loose all your written words. All that information must be still stored somewhere for a while. Must be some temp files somewhere (I used this trick a lot on Windows in order to recover Word texts).

Anyway, I think you got the idea. Do you know any Linux tool that can help recover discarded Gmail mails from an Android device? (I need something that works on 12.04 and in a Gnome environment.) Thanks!

Comment: I've got the feeling that a draft discarded immediately after having typed it wouldn't even be stored into the device in first place. If you actually at least saved it by, say, exiting the menu then it's different, you may try `photorec` and try to recover files matching a draft's MIME type (which I don't know what would it be, but it should be easy to look up). Did you actually discarded the draft right after having typed it or did the draft get stored somehow into the device at some point?

Comment: @kos - First of all, thanks for your reply. Well, as I've said in the question, I've been editing this draft during the entire last week. So, that means that I have been saving him for several times, not only ones. Today, I have opened the draft, read it, and, in a moment of lost attention, I've discarded the mail. But, prior to that I've made no other changes, not even a letter added to the original text. All I did, before discarding the text, was to read it.

Answer (score 0):

`testdisk` / `photorec` are good options for recovering deleted files, but I have no idea if the Gmail app even stores drafts as individual files on your device, or in one big "drafts" file. `testdisk` can recover simply deleted files that have not been overwritten yet, so that's an idea.

I don't have a perfect answer, but a few tactics that might work out.

You might want to consider searching through your entire device's storage with a hex editor (**[Bless](http://home.gna.org/bless/)** is one I like, graphic & works in Gnome) on the off chance that your draft was stored in plain text. And searching the entire device will look through every sector, in every file, deleted or not.

Searching a removable memory/SD card would easy, *if* the drafts were stored on it somewhere. Just remove it and put it in your computer, search away. But I don't know how easy or possible it is to search every sector of your Android's internal storage, or if it's even possible to do "remotely" from your computer. Maybe running an app or terminal on the device itself might work, running as "root" to search everywhere, so I suspect a rooted device would be required.

And the drafts could be stored in a compressed format too, so that's certianly an onion in the ointment.

---

If it was synced to Gmail's servers, then I'll bet they have a copy of it somewhere, but I haven't read anything useful about how to get a real person at Gmail to recover it.

---

Just a thought, I've used a program on Windows a long time ago that could search through all the RAM to look for text that was lost from a crashed notepad-type program. But a reboot normally resets/erases the RAM, and it could be overwritten at any time too.